# Why I can't get user data from firebase in my flutter project with user provider although there are data in firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my user model file,

```
  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    class User {
      final String uid;
      final String name;
      final String profileUrl;
      final String email;
      final List follwers;
      final List following;
      final List stars;
      final String developerbio;
      const User({
        required this.uid,
        required this.name,
        required this.profileUrl,
        required this.email,
        required this.follwers,
        required this.following,
        required this.stars,
        required this.developerbio,
      });
      // static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
      //   var snapshot =
      //       snap.data() != null ? snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic> : {};
    
      static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
        var snapshot =
            snap.data() != null ? snap.data() as Map<String,dynamic> : {};
       
        return User(
          uid: snapshot['uid'] ?? '',
          name: snapshot['name'] ?? '',
          profileUrl: snapshot['profileUrl'] ?? '',
          email: snapshot['email'],
          follwers: snapshot['followers'] ?? [],
          following: snapshot['following'] ?? [],
          stars: snapshot['stars'] ?? '',
          developerbio: snapshot['developerbio'] ?? '',
        );
      }
        Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => {
            "name": name,
            "uid": uid,
            "profileUrl": profileUrl,
            "email": email,
            "followers": follwers,
            "following": following,
            "stars": stars,
            "developer_bio": developerbio,
          };
    }
```

This is my dart file where I try to get data from firebase ,
but I don't get any data from that you can see that in photo.

```
>   import 'dart:typed_data';
> import 'package:error_solve_app/Screen/screens.dart';
> import 'package:error_solve_app/models/user_models.dart';
> import 'package:error_solve_app/provider/user_provider.dart';
> 
> import 'package:error_solve_app/widgets/button.dart';
> 
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
> import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
> 
> import '../utils/util.dart';
> 
> class AddQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
> 
> const AddQuestion({
> super.key, 
>   });
> 
>   @override
> State<AddQuestion> createState() => _AddQuestionState();
> }
> 
> class _AddQuestionState extends State<AddQuestion> {
> late final String hintText;
> 
> final TextEditingController controller = `TextEditingController();`
> Uint8List? file;
> 
> selectedImage() async {
> Uint8List? im = await pickedImage(ImageSource.gallery);
> if (im != null) {
> setState(() {
> file = im;
>       });
>     }
>   }
> 
>   @override
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> final User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
> 
> return Scaffold(
> appBar: AppBar(
> title: Text('Ask Question!'),
> backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
> leading: IconButton(
> icon: Icon(
> Icons.arrow_back,
> color: Colors.black,
>             ),
> onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
> MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreenLayout())),
>           )),
> body: SingleChildScrollView(
> child: Column(children: [
> const SizedBox(
> height: 20,
>           ),
> Row(
> children: [
> 
> 
> Text(
> user?.name?? '',
> style: TextStyle(
> color: Colors.black,
> fontSize: 20,
> fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
>               ),
>             ],
>           ),
> Container(
> decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
> height: 40,
> padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
> 
> child: TextField(
> maxLines: 10,
> controller: controller,
> decoration: InputDecoration(
> border: InputBorder.none,
> hintText: "Description",
> hintStyle: TextStyle(
> color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
>             ),
>           ),
> Row(
> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
> children: [
> file != null
> Padding(
> padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
> child: Image(
> image: MemoryImage(file!),
> width: 300,
>                       ),
>                     )
> Row(children: [
> IconButton(
> onPressed: selectedImage,
> icon: Icon(
> Icons.photo_album,
> color: Colors.green,
>                         ),
>                       ),
> Text('Add a Photo'),
>                     ]),
> Divider(
> color: Colors.grey,
>               )
>             ],
>           ),
> Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzQdj.png) 20)),
> MyButton(text: 'Create Post', onTap: (){
> print(user?.profileUrl??'');
>           }),
>         ]),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
```

And This is Authentication file

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:error_solve_app/services/storage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:error_solve_app/models/user_models.dart' as model;

class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<model.User> getUserDetails() async {
    User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;
    DocumentSnapshot snap =
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();
    return model.User.fromSnap(snap);
  }

  // sign up
  Future<String> signUpUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String username,
    required String developerbio,
    Uint8List? file,
  }) async {
    String res = " Some error occured";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty &&
          password.isNotEmpty &&
          username.isNotEmpty &&
          developerbio.isNotEmpty) {
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        print(cred.user!.uid);
        String profileUrl =
            "https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.jOs8yxy5gk0LNF4Mwg64tgAAAA&pid=Api&rs=1&c=1&qlt=95&w=117&h=117";
        if (file != null) {
          profileUrl = await StorageMethods()
              .uploadImageToStorage('profilePics', file, false);
        }
        //  add user to our database

        model.User user = model.User(
          uid: cred.user!.uid,
          name: username,
          profileUrl: profileUrl,
          email: email,
          follwers: [],
          following: [],
          stars: [],
          developerbio: developerbio,
        );
        await _firestore
            .collection('users')
            .doc(cred.user!.uid)
            .set(user.toJson());
        res = "success";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res = e.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }

  Future<String> LoginUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    String res = "some error occured";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty) {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        res = "success";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res = e.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }

  Future<void> SignOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

I don't have no idea why I can't get any data from database ,but in firebase I get all data .I want to get data from that please I highly
ask for for your help this my first time in this app, so I can make a lot of mistake if I did some mistakes ,I request to forgive me.
Here it the photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBydM.png)`

Comment: Thanks for everyone , I've just solved this error right now .I need to add this line"  Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).refreshUser();" before this line "final User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;"